# Como faço o relacionamento muitos para muitos no Ruby on Rails com has and belongs to many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabela-html, modelo-relacional, rails4, entidade-relacionamento

Tenho uma tabela sistema e uma tabela categoria, um sistema tem muitas categorias e uma categoria tem vários sistemas, queria usar a opção has_and_belongs_to_many do Rails (por ser uma relação simples e até para aprender a usar este recurso). Mas estou com dúvida na seguinte questão, tenho que criar uma migrate que gere uma table que guarda essas relações ou tipo o próprio Rails se encarrega disso, ao colocar o has_many_and_belong_to :sistemas e has_many_and_belong_to :categorias?

Alguém já usou, ou tem alguma sugestão/dica de como fazer?

Método do controller do sistema

```
def sistem_params
  params.require(:sistem).permit(:description, :categories)
end
```

Modelo Sistemas

```
class Sistem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  has_many :versions
end
```

modelo Categoria

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sistems

  has_many :tests
end
```

Migration da tabela que liga os modelos

```
class CategoriesAndSistems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_sistems do |t|
      t.references :category, :sistem
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Não tenho tempo agora para responder, mas sim, tem que ser feito a migração quando usa `has_many_and_belongs_to`. Você pode ver isso melhor aqui: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: Consegui criar a migrate, a table, e no console associar sistema com categoria, mas não consegui ainda fazer no controler e na view. Na view de create/edit de sistema quero poder selecionar em um select multiplo as categorias que ele tem, e ao salvar ele cria a associação, atualmente pelo console ele deixa associar mais de uma vez uma categoria para um sistema. Também estou tendo problema nos parametros de sistema, tentei adicionar categoriano (controler), tentei nested attributes e não está funcionando ele não deixa receber as categorias que estou tentando selecionar no form

Comment: Como você está mandando essa informação para o back-end? Coloque os modelos/migrações com as partes dos relacionamentos para eu entender melhor o problema.

Comment: Adicionei os códigos a descrição da pergunta @GabrielKatakura, precisa de alguma outra parte?

Comment: Já tentou `category_ids` (passando somente um array de IDs) em vez de `categories`?

Comment: posta o schema.db depois do migrate pra gente ver por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você cria uma tabela categorias_sistemas

```
create_table :categorias_sistemas, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :categoria, index: true
  t.belongs_to :sistema, index: true
end
```

e tanto na classe Categoria você adicionará o

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :sistemas
```

E na classe Sistema

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categorias
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Sugiro tomar um cuidado com classes em português pois a pluralização do Rails costuma ficar esquisita.